# Small module to write in a body field

Tags: drupal, module

I am trying to make a small module. The module should pull the body content from a certain node. This part works so far. Now I would write exactly this content back into the body field of the current node. But there I have a node in my head. How do I write the content into it? Maybe somebody can help me there briefly on the jumps.

My current code in the module:

`

```
<?php
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
/**
* Implements hook_form_alter().
*/
function copy_fields_from_model_contract_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

  $nid = 6766;
  $node_storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node');
  $node = $node_storage->load($nid);
  $contract1 = $node->field_vertragsinhalt->value;

if ($form_id == 'node_buch_anlegen_edit_form') {
  dpm($form);
  }
}
```

`
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly clear WHEN you are intending to perform this load/modify/save operation.  HOOK_form_alter (from above) will run every time a form is loaded on the site.

Your code above will load node(id:6766) every time a form loads, and then will kint your form if it's the edit form of any node of type buch_anlegen. So first, you want to either put all your logic specific to this form inside the if statment, or use hook_form_FORM_ID_alter. Second, I doubt you want to write the body field of node(id:6766) every time a node of type buch_anlegen is updated.

If you want to pre-populate all buch_anlegen node edit forms, then you are using the correct hook, but you will want to modify values in the $form_state variable.

If you want to modify all buch_anlegen nodes whenever they are saved, and add some text to the body field you could do something like the following

```
// Implements hook_entity_presave().
function copy_fields_from_model_contract_entity_presave(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) {
  $body_value = $entity->body->getValue();
  $body_value = $body_value . " Add this string to the body field".
  $entity->body->value = $body_value;     //set value for field
```

}

Of course this will add the string on every time the entity is saved, so you might want to do a check.

Note, that you do not have to call $entity->save() inside this hook, because it is a presave hook and could lead to infinite recursion. However if you were trying to do this elsewhere, you might reference this link:

https://www.heididev.com/how-programmatically-update-fields-value-drupal-8